# In Blazor, How to do something on long hover of an element? like show a popover after x seconds of long hover

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-server-side, .net-7.0

We can use Blazor's `@onmouseenter` event to check if the element is hovered over or not. But I want to check and show a popover on "long hover". For example, if the user hovers over the username of 2 seconds, only then the function attached to it may run and show a popover for user details

How can i achieve that?

Comment: I guess this is a javascript job, using setTimeout

Answer (score 3):

You could use `Task.Delay` with a cancellation token to trigger a class change on the element and then CSS to display the popover.

```html
<div class="@showHover" 
     data-hover="@someHelp" 
     @onmouseenter="showHelp" 
     @onmouseleave="cancelHelp">
    This is not clever
</div>
```

```cs
@code 
{
    CancellationTokenSource source = new();
    string showHover = "";
    string someHelp = "This is not helpful.";

    async Task showHelp()
    {
        try
        {
            await Task.Delay(1000,source.Token);
            showHover = nameof(showHover);
        }
        catch
        {
            showHover = "";
        }
        StateHasChanged();
    }
    void cancelHelp() 
    {
        source.Cancel();
        source = new();
        showHover = "";
    }
}
```

```css
  div {
      margin: 1rem;
      position:relative;
      border: solid thin gray;
      background: whitesmoke;
  }
  .showHover::after {
      content: attr(data-hover);
      position: absolute;
      top: calc(-5px - 100%);
      left: 0;
      background: gray;
      color: white;
  }
```

[Try it here](https://blazorrepl.telerik.com/cnEfQVlI59hgq4ei43)

Comment: I like this idea.